# In Common Lisp, could I do in-place arithmetic operations on a subgrid?

Tags: grid, common-lisp, in-place

I'm using `Antik` and `Gsll` for matrix calculations.

Sometimes I want to do arithmetic operations on a subgrid (for example, multiply a column of a matrix by 2.0). Now I have to write these codes:

```
(setf (grid:column mat 0) (gsll:elt* (grid:column mat 0) 2.0))
```

According to these codes, `Antik` has to first create a temporary grid for storing intermediate results, and then set it bask to the original `mat`. The creation of temporary grid can be slow when the matrix is huge. So I hope I can do this directly on the original `mat`.

**PS:** The `gsll:elt*` does in-place modification to the whole matrix, e.g. `(gsll:elt* mat 2.0)`, and this is very efficient even when the `mat` is huge.

### Update:

I'm showing the result of my experiment here:

Code:

```
(let ((mat (grid:make-simple-grid
             :grid-type 'grid:foreign-array
             :initial-contents
             (loop repeat 100 collect
                   (loop repeat 100 collect
                         (random 100))))))
  (time (loop repeat 1000 do
              (gsll:elt* mat 2.0)
              (gsll:elt* mat 0.5)))
  (time (loop repeat 1000 do
              (setf (grid:row mat 0) (gsll:elt* (grid:row mat 0) 2.0))
              (setf (grid:row mat 0) (gsll:elt* (grid:row mat 0) 0.5)))))
```

Result:

```
Evaluation took:
  0.016 seconds of real time
  0.016000 seconds of total run time (0.016000 user, 0.000000 system)
  100.00% CPU
  46,455,124 processor cycles
  353,280 bytes consed

Evaluation took:
  0.446 seconds of real time
  0.444000 seconds of total run time (0.420000 user, 0.024000 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.008 seconds GC time, and 0.436 seconds non-GC time. ]
  99.55% CPU
  1,308,042,508 processor cycles
  102,275,168 bytes consed
```

Note that the former calculation is taken on the whole 100x100 matrix, which is even faster than the the latter one (only taken on a 1x100 sub-matrix). And the latter one consed much more bytes due to the allocation of temporary storage.

Comment: Have you tested the effect of calling `elt*` for its in-place effect? I don't see a good reason to assume that it would modify a whole matrix in-place, but would refrain from doing so for a partial one.

Comment: @Rörd I have added my testing results.

Comment: What I mean is, have you tested whether replacing `(setf (grid:row mat 0) (gsll:elt* (grid:row mat 0) 2.0))` with just `(gsll:elt* (grid:row mat 0) 2.0)` will still yield the expected result on the matrix? If you leave out the `setf`, things should be faster.

Comment: @Rörd I have tested your case, and the `mat` remains unchanged. And I found it even faster if I manually operate each matrix element in-place.

Comment: Yes, sadly GSLL seems to misdesigned in this respect. `elt*` is always operating in-place, but just on the copy of the data from the matrix returned by `row`. The underlying C library, GSL, has functions that return views instead of copies of parts of the matrix, but these are not represented in GSLL. You could create a variant of `elt*` that will modify its subgrid argument in-place with this: `(define-modify-macro eltf* (b) elt*)`, but this will expand into the same `setf` operation that you were writing manually. So you would only get a shorter notation, but no speed increase.

Comment: @Rörd u're right. Maybe I should hack the code of Gsll for this feature.